# How to display post images in category view?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working with a theme I inherited that has been poorly coded.

The category view was displaying a horrible default youtube missing video picture at the top of each post snippet originally. I edited cateogry.php to this, and now the category view is working:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Category Archive pages.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage zelop
 */

get_header(); ?>

        <section class="main">

        <?php if( is_category( of_get_option('video_blog') ) ) : ?>

                     <h1 class="page-title"><?php
                      echo single_cat_title( '', false );
                  ?></h1>   

                  <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'archive' ); ?>


        <?php else : ?>     

                  <h1 class="page-title"><?php
                      echo single_cat_title( '', false );
                  ?></h1>   

                  <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'archive' ); ?>


         <?php endif; ?>       


        </section><!--end of main-->

        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    </section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

However when the category page is displayed there are no images appearing at the top of each snippet.

I would like the featured image of each post, to appear in the categories view, above the snippet, what code can I add to the category.php so that featured images for each post, are shown above the post snippet?

Comment: you will need to edit your `archive loop`

Comment: Thanks @cmorrissey I will check that out